# Cloud Speech-To-Text, cUrl to make a speech:recognize request, accessing file from my bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-speech

I'm a working with this tutorial : https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/transcribe-api?_ga=2.111344076.-975712240.1702582049

But I want to go further and copy the audio file provided in the tutorial in my own bucket.
But I don't understand why it doesn't work. I think it's because of credential. But I don't get it.

```
# Set PROJECT_ID variable
export PROJECT_ID=$(gcloud config get-value project)

#enable Cloud Speech-To-Text API
gcloud services enable speech.googleapis.com

#Create a bucket
gcloud storage buckets create gs://${PROJECT_ID}_bucket --project=$PROJECT_ID

#Store Audio file in the bucket
gsutil cp gs://cloud-samples-tests/speech/brooklyn.flac gs://${PROJECT_ID}_bucket

#Grant public access
gcloud storage objects update gs://${PROJECT_ID}_bucket/brooklyn.flac --add-acl-grant=entity=AllUsers,role=READER

# Create a service account
gcloud iam service-accounts create ServiceAccount1 \
    --description="DESCRIPTION" \
    --display-name="ServiceAccount1"
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT_ID \
    --member=serviceAccount:ServiceAccount1@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
    --role=roles/owner

# Create a key file for the service account
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create KEY_FILE.json \
    --iam-account=ServiceAccount1@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com

# Set your authentication environment variable
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="KEY_FILE.json"

# Create a JSON request file
echo '{
  "config": {
      "encoding":"FLAC",
      "sampleRateHertz": 16000,
      "languageCode": "en-US",
      "enableWordTimeOffsets": false
  },
  "audio": {
      "uri":"gs://${PROJECT_ID}_bucket/brooklyn.flac"
  }
}' > sync-request.json


#Use cUrl to make a speech:recognize request
curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $(cat $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS | jq -r .private_key)" \
    https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize \
    -d @sync-request.json
```

By the way, the original cUrl request was :

```
curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
    https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize \
    -d @sync-request.json
```

And the expected response is : (I have no response with the modified cUrl request)

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "alternatives": [
        {
          "transcript": "how old is the Brooklyn Bridge",
          "confidence": 0.98267895
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a 404 error :
'''
{
"error": {
"code": 404,
"message": "Requested entity was not found.",
"status": "NOT_FOUND"
}
}
'''

Comment: What is the error message? You created a service account, but granted (IAM policy binding) no IAM roles to give the service account permissions. Start with this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/policies)

Comment: Thanks a lot, updated my code to add : gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT_ID \
    --member=serviceAccount:ServiceAccount1@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
    --role=roles/owner

Comment: And I still have a 404 error, but I can the file in the bucket.  { "error": { "code": 404, "message": "Requested entity was not found.", "status": "NOT_FOUND" } } '''

Comment: I have found my mistake : I cannot use a PROJECT_ID variable in the JSON file. here : "audio": {
      "uri":"gs://${PROJECT_ID}_bucket/brooklyn.flac"

Answer (score 1):

I made 2 mistakes : I forgot to give a role to my service account and I left a $PROJECT_ID in the JSON file.

Here is a working code :

```
# https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/transcribe-api?_ga=2.111344076.-975712240.1702582049

# Set PROJECT_ID variable
export PROJECT_ID=$(gcloud config get-value project)

#enable Cloud Speech-To-Text API
gcloud services enable speech.googleapis.com

#Create a bucket
gcloud storage buckets create gs://${PROJECT_ID}_bucket --project=$PROJECT_ID

#Store Audio file in the bucket
gsutil cp gs://cloud-samples-tests/speech/brooklyn.flac gs://${PROJECT_ID}_bucket

#Grant public access
gcloud storage objects update gs://${PROJECT_ID}_bucket/brooklyn.flac --add-acl-grant=entity=AllUsers,role=READER

# Create a service account
gcloud iam service-accounts create ServiceAccount1 \
    --description="DESCRIPTION" \
    --display-name="ServiceAccount1"

#give a owner role to the service account
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT_ID \
    --member=serviceAccount:ServiceAccount1@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
    --role=roles/owner

# Create a key file for the service account
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create KEY_FILE.json \
    --iam-account=ServiceAccount1@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com

# Set your authentication environment variable
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="KEY_FILE.json"

# Create a JSON request file with PROJECT_ID replaced
echo '{
  "config": {
      "encoding":"FLAC",
      "sampleRateHertz": 16000,
      "languageCode": "en-US",
      "enableWordTimeOffsets": false
  },
  "audio": {
      "uri":"gs://'${PROJECT_ID}'_bucket/brooklyn.flac"
  }
}' > sync-request.json

# Set the endpoint URL
ENDPOINT="https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize"

#Use cUrl to make a speech:recognize request
curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token) \
    $ENDPOINT \
    -d @sync-request.json
```